# MvcSiteMapNode null on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a filter on a view which works on a form postback:

```
[Route("mypath/{param}/", Name = "myaction")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "My Form", ParentKey = "myparentaction", 
                Key = "myaction", PreservedRouteParameters = "param")]
public ActionResult myaction(string param) {
    // code
}


[Route("mypath/{param1}/{param2?}/{param3?}/{param4?}/")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myaction(string param1, string param2= "", int param3= 0, int param4= 0)
{
    // code
    var node = SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode;
    node.Title = param1;
}
```

On the view i have a form with some dropdown boxes and a hidden for the 4 params:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("myaction", "mycontroller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form" }))
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor( param2....   onchange = @"this.form.submit();"
   @Html.DropDownListFor( param3....   onchange = @"this.form.submit();"
   @Html.DropDownListFor( param4....   onchange = @"this.form.submit();"
   @Html.HiddenFor( param1....
}
```

On change of dropdowns it fires postback. When I first make a selection the current node is null. If i comment out this node code the filter works but only once. If I make another selection it 404s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this:

The reason it was not working (believe) is because I have a PreservedRouteParameters = "param"

In my postback that first parameter is called param1.

By changing the first parameter name to the same as the preserved one everything started working as expected.